# How to load resources without using an absolute path

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have some code in a Spring application that loads a file from a sub package (foo.bar.resources) of the current package:

```
package foo.bar

InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("./resources/facility.xml");
```

I would like to be able to move the xml file to the conventional resources folder but are unsure how to load it without using an absolute path

Comment: What is the exception ? FileNotFound ?? or something else

Comment: i doubt if there is any way to do this since we have to declare path

Comment: Where's the "conventional resources folder"? Still inside the jar?

Comment: Can you try using: `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(..)`

Comment: There is no exception.  The code as written works, however I would like to move to the xml file to the resources folder (or somewhere else on the classpath) and not have to specify an absolute path - maybe it is not possible?

Comment: If your file is in `procject\src\resources\file.xml` you should use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.xml");`. If your file is in other project folder (not in `/src`) -  use `new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\folder\\file.xml");`. I have tried both methods and both's works for me.